# Generating a categorical variable from an imputed variable

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, data-transformation, continuous-data, multiple-imputation

I am using multiple imputation to impute a continuous variable ($X$) with $\approx30\%$ missing values. I have a question regarding the generation of a new categorical variable ($Y$), starting from this imputed variable.

I want to use $Y$ as an independent variable in a logistic regression model instead of $X$ (I understand I'm losing information by doing this).

This is an example of how the categories in $Y$ would work:
$$
Y = \begin{cases}
    0 &{\rm if}\ \ \quad\quad\quad\!       X < 100         \\
    1 &{\rm if}\ \ 100\le X < 200  \\  
    2 &{\rm if}\ \ 200\le X < 300  \\  
    3 &{\rm if}\ \ 300 <  X  
    \end{cases}
$$

As imputed values vary between each set, I end up with a (not that much) different number of cases in each category of $Y$ on each imputed set.

Is this an appropriate approach if $X$ was imputed?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the imputed X as the variable? I don't see any advantage in this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The idea is to allow for easy interpretation and comparison with other studies by using standard reference points found in the literature.